# Reverse Arabic with English number changed position

Tags: java

I used the string builder reverse function to reverse Arabic and it's working as expected.

But if the string has an English number it's not working as expected.

EX: String str = "قباطلا 2 جرب 3";

the expected: "الطابق 2 برج 3"

current: "برج 2 الطابق 3"

My Code:

```
  public static String reverseArabic(String text){
  String retVal = null;
  if (text !=null){
   StringBuilder reversedString  = new StringBuilder(text);
   retVal = isArabic(text) ? reversedString.reverse().toString() : text;
   }
 return retVal;
}


public static boolean isArabic(String text){
   String textWithoutSpace = text.trim().replaceAll(" ", "");
   for(int i =0; i< textWithoutSpace.length();){
   int c= textWithoutSpace.codePointAt(i);
    if(c>= 0x0600 && c<=0x06FF || (c >= 0xFE70 && c<= 0xFEFF))
     return true;
    i+= Character.charCount(c);
     }
    return false;
 }
```

Comment: Without seeing your code it's impossible to say.

Comment: @tgdavies I added my code.

Comment: `isArabic` is actually `containsArabic` isn't it? You might be better to return a list of regions

Comment: @g00se could you please explain more, I didn't get you.

Comment: Instead of returning a boolean value which is of limited use return instead a list of regions of text that are in Arabic

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class Ar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            String s = "الطابق 2 برج";
            System.out.println(s);
            System.out.println(Ar.reverseArabic(s));
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static String reverseArabic(String s) {
        //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(getArabicPattern()).matcher(s);
        while (m.find()) {
            String tmp = s.substring(m.start(), m.end());
            m.appendReplacement(sb, new StringBuilder(tmp).reverse().toString());
        }
        m.appendTail(sb);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static String getArabicPattern() {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        result.append("[");

        for (char c = 0x0600; c <= 0x06FF; c++) {
            result.append(c);
        }
        for (char c = 0xFE70; c <= 0xFEFF; c++) {
            result.append(c);
        }
        result.append("]+");
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

I didn't think that an Arabic character class would work but that rather large one has seemed to quite well.